# Recipient didn't receive xmr that I sent

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-data, transaction-confirmation, exchange, balance

I'm still new to monero. I sent xmr 4 hours ago, and the recipient is telling me they haven't seen a change in their wallet. My wallet balance did go down. The transaction currently has 148 confirmations. I tried using the prove sending tab on xmrchain and it shows true for the amount sent. Are the funds lost forever or are there more steps I can take?